Generated HTML font size differs from original
I have a simple web page, which has a button which adds some text to the web page.  For some reason though, the added text seems to be a different size than the original text when viewed from a browser on a cell phone (but appeared OK when viewed from a browser running on a PC)
The long and short of it is, that I have the following in the test2.html file:
<p>extra1</p>
<div id="extra"></div>

Then I press a button which updates the <div>, and I get:
<p>extra1</p>
<div id="extra"><p>Note: if the game involves jumping into shallow water, please remind players to jump in feet first to avoid injury.</p><p></p></div>

(as cut and paste from a Chrome browser's 'inspect' dialog)
On a smartphone, the generated text has a much larger font size than the native text when viewed from a smartphone browser (I reproduced on two different android smartphones running chrome browsers).   This does not seem to occur when viewed from a PC, but that may be related to the default font size on the PC.
I do have a style listed in the <head> as so:
<style> h1 {font-size: 2em;} h2 {font-size: 1.4em;} p {font-size: .95em;} </style>

So I would expect the two paragraphs to display the same size.  Unfortunately, I was not able to produce a minimal example, however the test web page that reproduces it can be found at www.ulvr.com/swimactivities/test2.html -- again apologizing as I don't have a certificate for the web page, so it pops up warnings about being unsafe...   The chrome version that I have on my cell phone that reproduces the issue is 126.0.6478.122.
Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?

Make sure to add the viewport meta tag to avoid unexpected results on mobile.

I confirmed the issue of the larger output text in Chrome on Android. As Ralph commented, my testing showed that including the viewport meta tag in the <head> resolves the issue.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

screenshot without meta tag


screenshot with meta tag


You can try adding the viewport  tag :
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

